# Git: creating a filesystem state of a previous commit

Tags: git

I have clone of a repo. The project is new to me and I want to browse through an early commit (#abc) on my filesystem. How do I create a directory which mirrors a commit state? (I'm happy to lose the information after this commit). So if the commit #abc has only 3 files I want to have only these 3 files in my directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to every commit by:

```
git checkout checksumOfOldCommit .
```

---

To see checksums you can use

```
git log
```

Answer (score 0):

#### YOU CAN EASILY CHECKOUT TO A PERTICULAR COMMIT

```
git checkout [revision] .
```

`where [revision] is the commit hash (for example: 12345678901234567890123456789012345678ab)`

note: `don't forget to put . at end`